# python multithreading in loops

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, proxy, python-requests

I think I have a very basic understanding of how threading works, but since I don't know that much I can't figure this out. I want to have a pool limit of about 10 threads, but the tricky part is I don't know how to make it read line by line.

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://123.10.210.213:9999',
    'https': 'http://123.10.210.213:9999'
}


def create_proxy_lst(txt):
    print("""
########################################
#       WORKING    |      NOT WORKING  #
########################################
        """)
    proxy_list = []
    with open(txt) as f:
        for line in f:
            proxy_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
    return proxy_list


def check_proxy(website="https://google.com/"):
    working = 0
    not_working = 0
    total = 0
    lst = create_proxy_lst("uncheckedproxys.txt")
    for proxy in lst:
        try:
            proxies["https"] = "http://" + proxy
            proxies["http"] = "http://" + proxy
            r = requests.get(website, timeout=1, proxies=proxies)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                print("%s" % proxy)
                working += 1
                total += 1
                os.system("title Working: " + str(working) + "\t     Not working " + str(not_working) + "     ✔" + "    Total:   " + str(total) + "/" + str(len(lst)))
        except Exception:
            print("\t\t    %s" % proxy)
            not_working += 1
            total += 1
            os.system("title Working: " + str(working) + "\t     Not working " + str(not_working) + "     ✖" + "    Total:   " + str(total) + "/" + str(len(lst)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your proxies into a **[`Queue.Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects)**, and then start 10 threads to read proxy from the queue.

In your case:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def worker(proxy_queue):
    while not proxy_queue.empty():
        proxy = proxy_queue.get()

        working = 0
        not_working = 0
        total = 0

        try:
            proxies["https"] = "http://" + proxy
            proxies["http"] = "http://" + proxy
            r = requests.get(website, timeout=1, proxies=proxies)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                print("%s" % proxy)
                working += 1
                total += 1
                os.system("title Working: " + str(working) + "\t     Not working " + str(not_working) + "     ✔" + "    Total:   " + str(total) + "/" + str(len(lst)))
        except Exception:
            print("\t\t    %s" % proxy)
            not_working += 1
            total += 1
            os.system("title Working: " + str(working) + "\t     Not working " + str(not_working) + "     ✖" + "    Total:   " + str(total) + "/" + str(len(lst)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Build a queue
    proxy_queue = Queue()

    # Put these proxies into the queue
    with open("uncheckedproxys.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            proxy_queue.put(line.strip())

    # Create thread pool
    thread_pool = [Thread(target=worker, args=proxy_queue) for i in range(10)]

    # Start threads
    for thread in thread_pool:
        thread.start()
```